# Angular 2 AOT build error - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack, aot

My Angular 2 app is generated by [angular2-webpack-starter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-webpack-starter).

When I run command `npm run build:aot` to build AOT package, the console shows the following error message:

> .....
>      92% chunk asset optimization
>
> 500690 ms: Mark-sweep 1290.1 (1421.8) -> 1290.1 (1437.8) MB, 1219.8 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
>     501898 ms: Mark-sweep 1290.1 (1437.8) -> 1290.1 (1437.8) MB, 1207.9 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
>     503171 ms: Mark-sweep 1290.1 (1437.8) -> 1298.4 (1421.8) MB, 1272.9 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
>     504540 ms: Mark-sweep 1298.4 (1421.8) -> 1306.8 (1421.8) MB, 1368.3 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].

---

> Security context: 0000002FDCDCFB61 
>       2: enter [D:\Code\BIMS\node_modules\optimize-js\lib\index.js:~13] [pc=0000033281F0E5C5] (this=0000008415DEBED9 ,node=000003AAAC2EFB31 2
>       4: visit(aka visit) [D:\Code\BIMS\node_modules\estree-walker\dist\estree-walker.umd....
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
>     ......

I have followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955769/angular-2-aot-error-fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-javasc) to add --max-old-space-size=8192 option for Node.js, but it seems that there is no effect.

Comment: did you find a solution for this ? It seems to be impossible to resolve it for me now.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071399/javascript-heap-out-of-memory-in-angular-js-gulp-sourcemap-ngannonate-with-babel/57035956#57035956