# JavaScript heap out of memory in angular js gulp sourcemap ngannonate with babel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-ng-annotate

I am using es6 syntax in my angular JS project but it throws error when run `gulp build`, search over github and So but some saying this is error due to gulp uglify while some say this is babel issue and other say ng-annonate issue.

ubuntu **14.04**

node -v : **8.4.0**

npm -v : **5.3.0**

babel --version : **6.26.0** (babel-core 6.26.0)

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-open": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "browser-sync": "~2.9.11",
    "browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.3",
    "chalk": "~1.1.1",
    "del": "~2.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "estraverse": "~4.1.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "~1.1.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.8.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.0.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "~2.0.12",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "~3.0.1",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.2.0",
    "gulp-html-replace": "^1.6.1",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-inject": "~3.0.0",
    "gulp-less": "~3.0.3",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
    "gulp-merge": "^0.1.1",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-ng-config": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-nginxer": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-protractor": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "~0.5.4",
    "gulp-rev": "~6.0.1",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
    "gulp-size": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~1.4.1",
    "gulp-useref": "~1.3.0",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.6",
    "gulp-war": "^0.1.4",
    "gulp-zip": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp.spritesmith": "^6.3.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.9.0",
    "klaw-sync": "^1.1.2",
    "lodash": "~4.0.0",
    "main-bower-files": "~2.9.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "phantomjs": "~1.9.18",
    "uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
    "wiredep": "~2.2.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

*gulp/.babelrc*

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"],
    "plugins": ["syntax-decorators", "ng-annotate"] // this line is added after seeking for solution
}
```

*gulp/build.js* relevant code

```
.pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.babel({"presets": [ ["es2015", { "modules": false} ] ], compact: false}))
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.uglify({
      preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense
    })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
```

also tried  `.pipe(uglify({compress: {sequences: false, join_vars: false}}))` as per [this solution](https://github.com/Kagami/gulp-ng-annotate/issues/5) . but does not help

here is the log when execute `gulp build`

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[15435:0x303a4b0]   401581 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.9 (1459.1) -> 1399.9 (1459.1) MB, 3617.4 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested [15435:0x303a4b0]   405886 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.9 (1459.1) ->
1399.9 (1459.1) MB, 4101.3 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested [15435:0x303a4b0]   409592 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.9 (1459.1) -> 1399.9 (1459.1) MB, 3705.3 / 0.0 ms  last resort  [15435:0x303a4b0]   413501 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.9 (1459.1) -> 1399.9 (1459.1) MB, 3908.9 / 0.0 ms  last resort 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x1d10fec9cef1 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */ [/opt/project/path/node_modules/vinyl-sourcemaps-apply/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map/source-map-generator.js:~52] [pc=0x355474d0ca02](this=0xc4a489090d9 <JSGlobal Object>,mapping=0xbf1d8defe31 <Object map = 0xa04f5db0ae9>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 3->1
    3: forEach(this=0x11ebaae17be9 <JSArray[466526]>)
    5: SourceMapConsumer_ea...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory  1: node::Abort() [gulp]  2: 0x128fdfc [gulp]  3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [gulp]  4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [gulp]  5: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [gulp]  6: v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInTargetSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [gulp]  7: 0x3554749840dd Aborted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main cause was uglify plugin which does not work with es6 syntax so did this

1. `npm install babel-cli -g`
2. `bower install gulp-uglify-es --save-dev`
3. add plugin and update code in *gulp/build.js*

`var uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;`

and wrire belowcinside gulp task

```
 .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.babel({"presets": [ ["es2015", { "modules": false} ] ], compact: false}))
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(uglify()).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
```

update *package.json*

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-open": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.2.0",
    "chalk": "~1.1.1",
    "del": "~2.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "estraverse": "~4.1.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "~1.1.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.8.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.0.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-babel-minify": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "~2.0.12",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "~3.0.1",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.2.0",
    "gulp-html-replace": "^1.6.1",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-inject": "~3.0.0",
    "gulp-less": "~3.0.3",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
    "gulp-merge": "^0.1.1",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-ng-config": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-protractor": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "~0.5.4",
    "gulp-rev": "~6.0.1",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
    "gulp-size": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~1.4.1",
    "gulp-uglify-es": "^0.1.3",
    "gulp-useref": "~1.3.0",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.6",
    "gulp-war": "^0.1.4",
    "gulp-zip": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp.spritesmith": "^6.3.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.9.0",
    "klaw-sync": "^1.1.2",
    "lodash": "~4.0.0",
    "main-bower-files": "~2.9.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "phantomjs": "~1.9.18",
    "uglify-es": "^3.0.28",
    "uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
    "wiredep": "~2.2.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could simply be because your app needs a lot of memory to be built; node.js has a hard 1.4Gb limit for memory allocations. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356012/how-to-increase-nodejs-default-memory) on how to increase this limit. Let us know if this helps!

Comment: No. it was working fine since I have not used es6 syntax. this comes suddenly.

Comment: So, to clarify, without ES6 it was working, without ES6 it's **not** working?

Comment: sorry for the typo. Without using es6 syntax,  it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I after struggling for a while i managed to fixed this issue by replacing all **^** by **~** from the all the dependencies in `package.json` file.

**Replace**

```
  "dependencies": {
     "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.0",
    ...

  },
```

**To**

```
  "dependencies": {
     "@agm/core": "~1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    ...

  },
```

I think this issue is because of conflict between different version of libraries.