# JavaScript heap out of memory in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I am using Angular CLI. Please check my CLI info

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.1
node: 6.10.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.1.1
@angular/common: 4.0.0
@angular/compiler: 4.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.0
@angular/core: 4.0.0
@angular/forms: 4.0.0
@angular/http: 4.0.0
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.0
@angular/router: 4.1.1
```

When I use `ng serve --aot` I am getting the following error.

Last few GCs

> 893427 ms: Mark-sweep 1344.1 (1434.3) -> 1339.9 (1434.3) MB, 925.7 /
>   0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].   894468 ms: Mark-sweep 1339.9 (1434.3) -> 1339.9 (1434.3) MB, 1040.5 / 0.0 ms
>   [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].   895402 ms:
>   Mark-sweep 1339.9 (1434.3) -> 1339.6 (1418.3) MB, 933.7 / 0.0 ms [last
>   resort gc].   896331 ms: Mark-sweep 1339.6 (1418.3) -> 1339.8 (1418.3)
>   MB, 928.1 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].

JS stack trace

> Security context: 000001AF8A2CFB61 
>       2: /* anonymous */ [C:\project_folder\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:100]
>   [pc=0000016E99866533] (this=00000346870554E1 ,mapping=000003C18FDC93C9 )
>       3: arguments adaptor frame: 3->1
>       4: InnerArrayForEach(aka InnerArrayForEach) [native array.j...
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory

Comment: I think setting `--max_old_space_size` should help you see also this thread https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955769/angular-2-aot-error-fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-javasc,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517738/angular-cli-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-on-asset-optimization

Comment: I tried all .But still i am getting the same error. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2):

try to modify the files and replace their contents with the following:  (in the folder : node_modules\bin)

Modify ng.cmd:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=5048 "%~dp0\..\angular-cli\bin\ng" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node --max_old_space_size=5048 "%~dp0\..\angular-cli\bin\ng" %*
)
```

Modify ngc.cmd :

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=5048 "%~dp0\..\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node --max_old_space_size=5048 "%~dp0\..\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js" %*
)
```

Comment: it's not work properly..give same error after change

Comment: Replace all **^** to **~** from package.json .Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071399/javascript-heap-out-of-memory-in-angular-js-gulp-sourcemap-ngannonate-with-babel/57035956#57035956

Answer (score 1):

for angular 7, I increased the maximum memory allocated for budgets in angular.json file.

```
"budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "11mb"
                }
]
```

then ran the following command:
`node --max_old_space_size=10500 'node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng' build --prod`

in your case you should try to run this:
`node --max_old_space_size=10500 'node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng' serve --aot`

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes if the angular app will become bigger in size to compile. Please increase your node ram memory that will solve the issue. (Default node ram memory is 1600mb, increase it to around 3200)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue
In my tsconfig.json i had

> "include": [
>           "**/*"
>       ],

after removing this include, the ng build behave normal again